# How can I remove the marked space so it will fit the referance

Tags: html, css

Im new for html and css, I would like to know how can I improve my project so it will better fit the original design.

This is my live website: https://hbedikos.github.io/testimonal-grid/?fbclid=IwAR30LzSdRPmGM8fmANxvivUuWJaqpnRNchH0S-sw3jS2Dov0FeHgknYkSoY 
how can I remove the marked space in the image 1 and make the whole container smaller, so it will fit image 2 as much as possible
My work: [image]

Original Design: [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fit content for either *Height* or *Width* Just Like -

```
width: fit-content; // Or you can give in % here
height: fit-content; // Or you can give in % here
```

In short whichever you want to be dynamic with your content keep `fit-content`!

Remember to have your parent *DIV* ready with some *max-height* or *max-width* (Whichever you want to keep it Fixed)